# X-Storage-Url and X-Auth-Token?

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

I'm following a tutorial to install swift openstacl object storage, in the lattests steps it ask me to do this : ------- **"curl -v -H 'X-Storage-User: test:tester' -H 'X-Storage-Pass: testing' url:8080/auth/v1.0"** ------to Get an X-Storage-Url and X-Auth-Token and after that cheking that i can get an account by typing : curl -v -H 'X-Auth-Token:token-from-x-auth-token-above' url-from-x-storage-url-above

Have any one an idea what such command can mean ? i don't really understand its rules ! i know it's king of identification, but what exactly mean ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, you send your password and account to Swift, and then Swift sends back token and url to you. Token stands for a authenticated account/password pair. URL stands for who is responsible for this account. In reality settings, there can be two groups of proxy servers: A and B. A is only for authentication. B is for storage access. After authentication, A sends back `X-Storage-Url` to user, and the `X-Storage-Url` is B's doman name.

You can use the token and the url to access storage.
For example,

`curl -v -H 'X-Auth-Token: <token>' <url>` means you can access the account

`curl -v -H 'X-Auth-Token: <token>' <url>/container_name -XPUT` means you want to create container `container_name` under the account.

`curl -v -H 'X-Auth-Token: <token>' <url>/container_name/object_name -T localfile` means you want to upload `localfile` to the container and name it `object_name`.

The token is generated by the middleware. In Swift, there are 3 auth middlewares you can choose: tempauth, swauth, and keystone.

You can also set different X-Storage-Urls for different accounts, if you have load-balancing concerns.

Comment: Sorry for this huge late replay, i just saw it, and magically you've responded indirectly on a question that i asked now in the forum, (upload file by curl)...Thank's also for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`enter code here`curl `curl is a tool to transfer data from or to a server, using one of the supported protocols (DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, GOPHER, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMB, SMBS, SMTP, SMTPS, TELNET and TFTP). The command is designed to work without user interaction`

So once you Issue

```
curl -i -X GET -H 'X-Auth-User: myaccount:me' -H 'X-Auth-Key: secretpassword' http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/v1.0
```

curl is setting up the Header namely Key,Value Pair to Swift Auth System to validate with TempAuth system
The header are

```
X-Auth-User
X-Auth-Key
```

Finally you will get a OK if AUTH passes

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

and if you see the Header it will contains the information like

```
X-Storage-Url: http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/AUTH_myaccount
X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tk7790238141c343bdb6ad1303e3d3bc00
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Storage-Token: AUTH_tk7790238141c343bdb6ad1303e3d3bc00
Content-Length: 0
X-Trans-Id: txab863ae755ec4c8d9aa19-0054bfda6f
Date: Wed, 21 Jan 2015 16:57:19 GMT
```

Here is sample link that explains the [TempAuth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKTwSYPVlnA)